# IsCancellationRequested no me funciona

Tags: ajax, mvc

me pasa una cosa muy rara que no entiendo,
necesito lanzar un proceso con ajax y poder cancelarlo, en mi proyecto real a veces dura muchisimo ya que el volumen es muy grande a veces. (cargo datos desde vistas SQL, Proceso informacion y finalmente cargo en Base de datos y subo ficheros a Servidor SSH) .

Hice una prueba de lanzar un pequeño proceso y pararlo en un proyecto aparte y me funciona.

este seria el codigo.

VISTA:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}



<div class="form-group row ">
    <div class=" col-sm-7 col-md-11 text-right">
        <button type="button" id="btcComenzar" class="btn btn-primary" onclick=" Comenzar(); ">Comenzar</button>
        <button type="button" id='btnCancelar' class="btn btn-primary" onclick=" Cancelar(); ">Cancelar</button>
    </div>
</div>

<br />

  

<script>
 

    function Comenzar()
    {
        console.log('0Comenzar');
        var url = '@Url.Action("Comenzar", "Home")';
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                cache: false,
                async : true,
                url: url,
                datatype: 'json',
                data: {
                },
                success: function (data) {

                    alert(data)
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert(error.Message);
                }
            })

    }

    function Cancelar() {

            var url = '@Url.Action("Cancelar", "Home")';
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                cache: false,
                async : false,
                url: url,
                datatype: 'json',
                data: {
                },
                success: function (data) {

                   // alert('cancelado')
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert(error.Message);
                }
            })
    }

</script>
```

CONTROLADOR:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public static CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource = null;

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<JsonResult> Comenzar()
        {
            try
            {
                _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
                var token = _tokenSource.Token;

                var obj = new prueba();                           
                var res = await Task.Run(() => obj.Contar(token));

                //if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                //{
                //    return Json("Cancelado nivel1", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                //    //token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                //}

                return Json(res, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

            catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
            {
                return Json("Cancelado Exception", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                return Json("Error Exception ", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            finally {
                _tokenSource.Dispose();
            }
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Cancelar()
        {
            try
            {
                _tokenSource.Cancel();               
                return Json("ok", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                return Json("ERR", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
         
    }
```

CLASE :

```
 public class prueba
    {
        public String Contar(CancellationToken token)
        {
            String res = "";
            return Contar2(token);
            
        }

        public String Contar2(CancellationToken token)
        {
            return Contar3(token);

           
        }

        public String Contar3(CancellationToken token)
        {
            String res = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                // Console.WriteLine("numero " + i.ToString());

                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    return "Cancelado desde contar3";
                    //token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                }

            }
            return "Fin de conteo desde contar3";
        }
    }
```

y esto me funciona , me aparece el mensaje de "Cancelado desde contar3" pero cuando me lo paso a mi proyecto de MVC no me funciona, Que puede estar pasando?

La unica diferencia es que la prueba esta desarrollada en .NET Core, y mi proyecto es de MVC Framework 4.6.1.

Me puede ayudar alguien ?

Gracias!